# libgdx/Android: graphics disappearing after the app is destroyed/paused

Tags: java, android, opengl-es, libgdx, textures

I was doing some tests and I realized that on my Nexus 5, when I hit the back key (or the home) -*that is, when there's a change of context*- and I go back to my game, the openGL context is lost.

There are no textures anymore (they show as black) or skins for the UI (the buttons are white).

I thought it was automanaged by libgdx automatically, right? So why is this happening?

The way I'm creating the textures is via `TextureAtlas`, like

```
TextureAtlas atlas;
TextureRegion bg;
atlas = new TextureAtlas(Gdx.files.internal("mainMenu.atlas"));
bg = atlas.findRegion("bg");
```

And then it's used with the `batch.draw(bg, x, y, w, h);`

I also tried creating the `TextureRegion` loading directly a Texture instead of a `TextureAtlas` (just in case but it should be the same) and I get the same result...

Anyone?

Edit: more specific code:

Screen class basics:

```
public class MainMenuScreen extends ScreenManager.Screen {

        private Game game;
    private InputMultiplexer inputMultiplexer = new InputMultiplexer();

    private MainMenuUi screenUi;
    private MainMenuView screenView;

    private TextureAtlas atlas;

    public MainMenuScreen(ConbiniGame game) {
        this.game = game;

        atlas = new TextureAtlas(Gdx.files.internal("mainMenu.atlas"));
        screenUi = new MainMenuUi(game);
        screenView = new MainMenuView(atlas);

        inputMultiplexer.addProcessor(screenUi.getInputProcessor());
        inputMultiplexer.addProcessor(screenView.getInputProcessor());

        Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(inputMultiplexer);
    }

    // ...
}
```

MainMenuView class where the TextureAtlas is being used...

```
public class MainMenuView {

    private Stage stage;
    private OrthographicCamera camera;
    private Viewport viewport;

    private TextureAtlas atlas;
    TextureRegion bg;

    public MainMenuView(TextureAtlas atlas) {
        atlas = atlas;
        bg = atlas.findRegion("bg");

        camera = new OrthographicCamera();
        camera.setToOrtho(false);
        viewport = new FitViewport(1080, 1920, camera);
        stage = new Stage(viewport);
    }

    public void update(float delta) {
        stage.act(delta);
    }

    public void render() {
        Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

        stage.getBatch().begin();
        stage.getBatch().draw(bg, 0, 0, stage.getCamera().viewportWidth, stage.getCamera().viewportHeight);
        stage.getBatch().end();

        stage.draw();
    }

    public InputProcessor getInputProcessor() {
        return stage;
    }
}
```

The code is just to show the use of the texture, with other parts removed

Answer (score 4):

You didn't provide enough information, but your problem is likely caused by using `static` in your code. Don't do that.

When you press the back button your app is closed. When you press the home button then your app is paused. Note that this are two different things. Therefor you might experience the problem not always when using the home button. This because while your app is paused, that android might decide to close it (to free memory), but it is not guaranteed to do so.

Either way, this is not related to the opengl context being lost. It is just closed. If the context would be really lost then libgdx (and later versions of android) will recover it for you.

When you close your app and then immediately start it again then Android might reuse the same VM for that instance of your app. This also means that any `static` variables will have the value they had from the previous run of your app. If any of those variables include (may be indirectly) any resources, then those resources won't be valid anymore.

tl;dr never use `static` in android applications.

The most common mistake (without seeing your code this is just guessing) is to access assets by using a singleton. E.g. `MyGame.getInstance().assets.get("atlas",...);` don't do that, it will (because of above reason) fail. Instead pass a reference to your `MyGame` instance to whichever classes needs it (e.g. your `Screen`: `new MenuScreen(this);`).

Comment: I understand. Didn't know that about statics in android. Just starting ;) I'll try now without statics but then, if i understand correctly, you recommend to store all the asset managers as instance variables of the main Game class, right? thanks

Comment: That was just an example. If it works for you to make an assets member to your game, then use that, if you prefer something else then use that. But don't use statics. Btw, you should never ever have more than one AssetManager instance.

Comment: I tried removing the singleton, static, etc. Now the texture is being loaded into a instance variable of the screen... and the problem still happens... any other idea?

Comment: As said, you haven't provided enough information. http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: was updating the question with more specific code ;)

Comment: That code doesn't compile. Read the link I gave, specifically http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: In the end, while I was trying to prepare a better code, I found this page http://www.jacobplaster.net/using-libgdx-asset-manager where says that all the resources needs to be loaded again in the resume() method of a screen...
That's why I was asking about the textures being self managed, but if you need to that I don't see the point, or is it that this page is wrong? 
Anyways I got a different problem, but it will become a new question.

Comment: You *do not* have to reload resources in the resume method. Even more, only calling `AssetManager#finishLoading()` will not have any effect in the resume method, *that call will not reload* anything. LibGDX will reload them for you as needed. You can, however, show a loading screen when libGDX does that. In which case you would need to call `Texture.setAssetManager` and then handle the updating yourself, see: https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Managing-your-assets#resuming-with-a-loading-screen

Comment: uhm, that's true. Then I don't know why my graphics are not being reloaded by libgdx. Funny thing, in my test game I did before, I had no problems, even loading all assets in static fields. Now I'm not using static and I have this problem... :s I'll try to reproduce it again in a minimal enviroment =_=

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem when making my first LibGDX game - a Flappy Bird clone - and it turned out the problem was not with the Texture at all, but with a MEMBER Vector2/Vector3 variable that I used for velocity.

To make the bird fall from a given height, I'd declared:
1. a member int variable for gravity (initialised to -15), 
2. a Vector2 member variable for bird position, initialised to (50, 300), and
3. another Vector2 member variable for velocity, initialised to 0,0

Now, in the update() method, I passed gravity as a value to velocity's y-axis parameter using velocity.add(0, gravity)

Then I scaled it, using velocity.scl(dt)
Then I added that velocity to position and then unscaled it again, using velocity. scl(1/dt). 
This last line was what caused the bug, but since it was essential for the functionality of my game, I couldn't afford to delete.
My solution was to change the velocity variable from a member variable to a local variable, and the textures stopped disappearing when game was paused.

Answer (score 0):

Actually it's OK to use Singleton or other static paterns for texture management. The only thing you should do to escape black-rectangle problem is:
make static content depending of Game entity:

```
private static TextureStore sStore = null;
private static MyGdxGame sGame;

static public TextureStore getStore()
{
    if(sStore==null||sGame!=MyGdxGame.getGame())
    {
        sStore = new TextureStore();
        sGame = MyGdxGame.getGame();
    }
    
    return sStore;
}
```

And in game entity

```
@Override
public void create()
{
    sGame = this;
...
```