# Disposing Asset Manager in LibGDX

Tags: java, android, libgdx, assets, asset-management

Here is my OOP setup:

**Class MainGame extends Game**:

...

```
public void create () {
    assets = new Assets(); // my custom Assets object (constructor creates manager and AssetDescriptors
    assets.load(); // loads Asset Descriptors into manager
    assets.getManager().finishLoading();
    batch = new SpriteBatch();
    setScreen(new PlayScreen(this, assets));
}
```

...

```
public void dispose () {

    assets.dispose(); // disposes asset manager
    super.dispose();
    batch.dispose();
}
```

**Class PlayScreen implements Screen:**

```
public PlayScreen(MainGame game, Assets assets) {

    this.assets = assets;
    this.game = game;

    background = assets.getManager().get(assets.getBackground());
    hero = new HeroSprite(290, 1100, this, assets);

    // Create Game camera and Hub also
}

public void render(float delta) {

    // Clear screen
    // Use game batch to draw to screen

}

public void dispose() {
    assets.dispose();
}
```

**Class HeroSprite:**

```
public HeroSprite(int x, int y, PlayScreen screen, Assets assets){

    this.assets = assets;
    this.screen = screen;

    // Animation Textures
    heroWalking = assets.getManager().get(assets.getWalking()); // This is an Asset Descriptor

    walkAnime = new Animation(heroWalking) // my own custom animation class which takes the spritesheet and returns the appropriate frames

    ...

 }

// This does not contain a dispose method
```

Sorr if there's a lot of code there I tried to minimize as much as possible. My main question is if I am disposing correctly?

It seems ok, my game runs fine. But when I quit the game and re-enter a black screen shows. This happens both on Desktop and Android.

A solution that works is to clear the memory on Android using Super Cleaner App. Since it's a memory issue I figures it has something to do with me disposing incorrectly.

**EDIT : Revealing my Assets Class**

```
public class Assets {

    private AssetManager manager;

    private AssetDescriptor<Texture> background;
    private AssetDescriptor<Texture> wood;

    public AssetManager getManager() {
        return manager;
    }

    public AssetDescriptor<Texture> getBackground() {
        return background;
    }

    public AssetDescriptor<Texture> getWood() {
        return hero;
    }    

    public Assets(){

        manager = new AssetManager();

        background = new AssetDescriptor<Texture>("textures/static/bg.png", Texture.class);
        hero = new AssetDescriptor<Texture>("textures/static/hero.png", Texture.class);
        ...

    }

    public void load(){

        manager.load(background);
        manager.load(hero);
        ...

    }

    public void dispose(){
        manager.dispose();
    }
}
```

Comment: what is the need of disposing assets from dispose() method of PlayScreen ?

Comment: how you exit your Game ? Are you using Gdx.app.exit(); ?

Comment: On desktop I click 'X' button. On Android I swipe App away. I've never used `Gdx.app.exit()`

Answer (score 0):

`Screen.dispose()` [does not get called automatically](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/Screen.html), you should manually call dispose when you exit a screen and not needing the assets anymore. But obviously when you need them again you need to load them again and you need a `new AssetManager` for that. So if your assets won't take up that much you should just keep it in memory.

On exit however you need to dispose. `Game.dispose()` does get called automatically. Here you should call `getScreen().dispose()` and have everything needing disposing in the `dispose()` method of the effective `Screen`.

Since currently it does not look like you are disposing between screens it might be because you have a static AssetManager, you should show your `Assets()` class.

Comment: assets object already disposing from dispose() method of Game class then what is the need to call getScreen().dispose() for disposing assets object. As the given reference Assets object create once from create() method of Game so it must be not disposed from Screen dispose() method. Currently owner disposed assets from dispose() method of Screen but he not called this method.

Comment: @AbhishekAryan `SpriteBatch` is not being disposed. If you have a `Stage` there it's neither getting disposed.

Comment: Ok, I'm trying to keep up. First of all, my asset manager is not static. In fact, almost every variable in my game is private. Also, SpriteBatch is being disposed in the Game class.

Comment: @Madmenyo Owner using SpriteBatch of Game class which is disposing in dispose() method of Game class. In render() method of Screen owner mention that he is only using SpriteBatch of Game class  for rendering via comment, no any Stage there.

Comment: Correct. I'm not using a stage. The game batch object is used to draw to screen which is passed down into Screen's constructor from Game class.

Comment: @AbhishekAryan yes indeed, my mistake. But `dispose()` in `GameScreen` is never being called, as far as I can see. If he is closing the game with the "X" on Desktop and this happens the AssetManager remains in a disposed state and does not get assigned a `new AssetManager()` it's all I can think about. AFAIK this could only happen if you create a static `AssetManager`.

Comment: I have edited my question to show the Asset Manager. As you can see it is not static. Is there possibly a form of debugging I could use to test disposing?

Comment: How about you call `finishLoading()` on `show` method. They are probably not loaded, no idea why but loading them anyway on `show()` makes sure this is the problem.

Comment: Ok, I will try that. Do you know if I should I call `background.dispose()` in Screen dispose method? Since it's referencing the texture in the Asset Manager this shouldn't be necessary, right? I'm starting to run out of ideas now.

Comment: Thought so. Calling `finishLoading()` in `show` crashes the game. I also tried moving `load()` into `show` but didn't fix it

Comment: @GregPeckory Well, your `AssetManager` is not being reinitialized properly when you exit and reload the game. Unfortunately I have no clue why.

Comment: Ok. Thanks for all the help !! If I end up figuring it out I will post the answer here.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31137930/libgdx-android-graphics-disappearing-after-the-app-is-destroyed-paused are you sure you are not using any statics regarding to your assets? I had the same issues with black textures when I started out with LibGDX. Read the AssetManager docs, do it properly and it really should just work.